# Is it normal for motorcycles to switch off if they are not revved after several hours of being idle?

Tags: engine, yamaha

I have a Yamaha YZF R125 and I am noticing that after it has been unused for several hours, such as after the night or after work, as soon as I start it, if I do not rev it a bit, revs gets really low and it switches off. If I rev it a bit for 10 seconds or so, then it can remain idle without any issues.

I am new to riding and hence bear with me, but is this normal for motorcycles? Or maybe motorcycles with small engines?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like normal behavior. Is there a manual choke on that bike? Maybe you could use that for 30 seconds to avoid it dying.

Answer (score 1):

Its not unusual really for a single cylinder bike to stall when cold.. As a cold single cylinder engine is in a rather imbalanced state until it warms up. 
If it were stalling once it was getting warmed up then that would perhaps require a little investigation/attention, but only just to perhaps raise the tickover speed slightly.